# How to get full AssertionError report without removing the Stack Frame in TestNG?

Tags: java, testng

I use Selenium with TestNG.

I got following exception, when trying to get a element using `Assert.fail();`

The need is, **I want to get the full stack frames**. In the exception the removed stack frames ("Removed 24 stack frames") printed at the bottom of the exception.
But I want to print all the stack frames in the report.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Elements[id, newDocName] was Not Visible
after waiting for 1 Minute

at processor.WebdriverActions.writeFailure(WebdriverActions.java:2213)

at
processor.WebdriverActions.waitForElementVisible(WebdriverActions.java:1015)

at
testcases.NewUI_Animation_All.TC001_PresentationCreation_ChooseTheme(NewUI_Animation_All.java:12)

... Removed 24 stack frames
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't describe how you run your tests, but if you want the complete Stacktrace, you can:

- Use system property: `-Dtestng.show.stack.frames=true` JVM option or `System.setProperty("testng.show.stack.frames", "true")` in your code
- Configure an higher verbose level (full stacktrace starts with `verbose>=2`)

Comment: I run shell files which executes testng xml. And System.setProperty("testng.show.stack.frames", "true")  Worked for me.